# Task Scheduler (run whether user is logged on or not)

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, privileges

I'm having a problem with scheduling a task in Windows 7
I m creating a task which is mapped to a bat file to execute,
here is my .bat file :

```
cd "C:\soft\" 
Start excel "" "AD Auto Run.xlsm"
```

its working automaticaly and manually when the option (radio button) "Run only when the user is logged on" is selected.

but the automatic/manual RUN is not working when the option (radio button) "Run whether user logged on or not" is selected.

Comment: Can you define 'working'. What is supposed to happen? What does your Excel file do? Can you include the code from it?

Comment: the excel file generate reports

Comment: Does it store the reports on a mapped drive?

Comment: look, here is a description of what I make : I created a .bat file that launch a .xlsm (1) file, in this file I call another .xlsm (2) file that generate me the reports , I proceeded in this manner because otherwise the 2nd file will be opened in a already opened instance of excel which can cause problem if I have excel file already open. that's why I proceeded in this way. (.bat-->(1).xlsm-->(2).xlsm  so the seconde xlsm will be opened in the fisrt one)

Comment: in the case when I check the (run whether user is logged on or not), the first .xslm file will not be opened so te second will not be called, that's why i think it's not related to the mapped drive

Comment: But are you using a mapped drive? Mapped drives will only be available once a user has logged in.

Comment: Nop I haven't
PS: Even when I'm logged in and i try to start the task with the "Run only when the user is logged on selected" i get nothing (i checked my log file and I found that the task was executed without problem !!!)

Comment: I'm logged with a remote desktop connexion tool , but I'm sure that I have the Highest privileges

Comment: Are you running the scheduled task with your account credentials?

Comment: with admin credentials

Answer (score 0):

Check the mapped drive in your batch file, by adding a diagnostic command after you map the drive.

Assuming M: is the mapped drive:

```
if exist "M:\soft\AD Auto Run.xlsm" (
   >>"c:\folder with write permissions\file.log" echo map ok
   ) else (
   >>"c:\folder with write permissions\file.log" echo map FAILED
 )
```

Comment: here is th message on the file.log: map ok

Comment: If you ran it as a scheduled task where it was failing before, and you entered the right drive letter - then your mapping is working.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes and it appears to work like a charm. The issue like I previously stated that the excel is creating some issue. 
I found that the excel file was not able to save the record set output when the user account is logged off.
So You have to create a folder (or two on a 64bit-windows):

(32Bit, always)
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop
(64Bit)
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop
After creation of the folder, my program is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by performing these steps:

Create the empty Desktop folders at the below path:

C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop

Make sure user has “log on as batch job” permission.

To enable this please follow below steps:

a) Go to the Start menu.

b) Type secpol.msc. and press Enter.

c) The Local Security Policy manager opens.

d) Go to Security Settings - Local Policies - User Rights Assignment node.

e) Double click Log on as a batch job on the right side.

f) Click Add User or Group.

g) Select the user.

h) Click OK.

Create a file and save it with .cmd extension. The .cmd file should contain below cmd:

```
cscript.exe “<path to .vbs file>”
```

In the scheduler, give the path as follows:

• Program/script: filename (.cmd filename)

• Start in(optional): file path (path to .cmd file)